# VBA: cannot work with PivotTable (error 1004)

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, pivot-table

Okay, I really am frustrated right now. For the past hour or so I have been trying to get data from a simple Pivot. I cannot get it to work.

My really simple code:

```
Sub getXXFromPivot()

     Dim test As PivotTable

     Set Sheet1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5")
     Set test = Sheet1.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
     Set test2 = test.ClearAllFilters

     MsgBox test2

End Sub
```

I am trying to use the "`GetPivotData`" method to get data, but no matter what I use after `test.` (`ClearAllFilters` was just a test) I always end up with error 1004. What is my mistake here? I cannot figure it out.
"PivotTable1" definitely exists. I can `MsgBox test` and get "PivotTable1" back.

Comment: You probably want to do `test.ClearAllFilters` instead of `Set test2 = test.ClearAllFilters`. Also, the message in the message box has to be a string, which `test` is not. Also you should declare `Sheet1` with a different name.

Comment: Are you sure you get `1004`? This code `test2 = test.ClearAllFilters` should return "type mismatch" error.

Comment: @DarXyde True, that was stupid. Clearing the filters works fine without the Set, but I still do not know how to get any data from the Pivot. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may decide to use `TableRange1` or `TableRange2`properties of the PivotTable and loop through them. This is the main difference:

- [TableRange1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.tablerange1) - Returns a Range object that represents the range containing the entire PivotTable report, but doesn't include page fields. Read-only.
- [TableRange2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.tablerange2) - Returns a Range object that represents the range containing the entire PivotTable report, including page fields. Read-only.

---

```
Sub GetXXFromPivot()

     Dim pt As PivotTable
     Dim wks As Worksheet

     Set wks = Worksheets(1)
     Set pt = wks.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

     Dim myResult As Range
     Set myResult = pt.TableRange2

     Dim myCell As Range
     For Each myCell In pt.TableRange2.Cells
        Debug.Print myCell
     Next myCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to my comment, please see bellow an adaptation of your code:

```vb
Option Explicit 'Is recommended to use this always
Sub getXXFromPivot()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim pTbl As PivotTable

    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5")
    Set pTbl = sht.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    pTbl.ClearAllFilters

    MsgBox pTbl.Name

End Sub
```

As a pretty good source on how to work with pivot tables, see [The VBA Guide To Excel Pivot Tables](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/9/27/vba-guide-excel-pivot-tables)

Comment: Thank you. This works so far. What I need in the end is a List/an Array of the data in the Pivot. Its just one Column without section. How would I go about that?

Comment: use the function `GetPivotData(field,pivottable,filter1,criteria1,filter2,criteria2...)`